# How to read environment variables of a process

Tags: linux, process, environment-variables

Linux's `/proc/<pid>/environ` does not update a process's environment. As I understand it, the file contains the initial environment of the process.

How can I read a process's *current* environment?

Comment: `ps e -ww -p <PID>`

Comment: possible shortest answer: `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$pid/environ`(based on comment https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process#comment938505_389418)

Comment: Both of the above suggestions still only report the **initial** environment of the process, not the **current** as this question requests.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`/proc/$pid/environ` does update if the process changes its own environment. But many programs don't bother changing their own environment, because it's a bit pointless: a program's environment is not visible through normal channels, only through `/proc` and `ps`, and even not every unix variant has this kind of feature, so applications don't rely on it.

As far as the kernel is concerned, the environment only appears as the argument of the [`execve`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execve) system call that starts the program. Linux exposes an area in memory through `/proc`, and some programs update this area while others don't. In particular, I don't think any shell updates this area. As the area has a fixed size, it would be impossible to add new variables or change the length of a value.

Comment: so, effectively there is no way to access the process' *envp (array of pointers to environment settings).  @Gilles, can you please show if it is possible to attach the debugger and read the array of pointers to environment settings.

Comment: @Nikhil Sure, it is. But just because you write `PATH=foo` in a shell doesn't mean the shell is going to modify `*envp`. In some shells, that only updated an internal data structure, and it's the external program execution code that updates `*envp`. Look at `assign_in_env` in `variables.c` in the bash source, for example.

Comment: @Gilles: This answer is at best misleading (-1). The environment in /proc/$$/environ is read from the process's stack. See fs/proc/base.c. This is the initial environment. It is never updated and in fact can't be. The environment that the libc setenv uses is allocated on the heap and initialized with the contents of the environment in the stack. If the process calls libc's ``fork`` then libc makes the ``sys_fork`` call using the heap allocated environment for the child process.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham You're right that the initial environment isn't updated in any shell. However that area is not read only under Linux, I've encountered programs that use it to report their status (status reports through `argv` are more common but both exist).

Answer (score 60):

You can read the **initial** environment of a process from `/proc/<pid>/environ`.

If a process **changes** its environment, then in order to read the environment you must have the symbol table for the process and use the `ptrace` system call (for example by using `gdb`) to read the environment from the global `char **__environ` variable. There isn't any other way to get the value of any variable from a running Linux process.

That's the answer. Now for some notes.

The above assumes that the process is POSIX compliant, meaning that the process manages its environment using a global variable `char **__environ` as specified in the [Ref Spec](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---environ.html).

The initial environment for a process is passed to the process in a fixed-length buffer on the process's stack. (The usual mechanism that does this is `linux//fs/exec.c:do_execve_common(...)`.) Since the size of the buffer is calculated to be no more than the size required for the initial environment, you can't add new variables without erasing existing variables or smashing the stack. So, any reasonable scheme to allow changes in a process's environment would use the heap, where memory in arbitrary sizes can be allocated and freed, which is exactly what GNU `libc` (`glibc`) does for you.

If the process uses `glibc`, then it is POSIX compliant, with `__environ` being declared in `glibc//posix/environ.c` Glibc initializes `__environ` with a pointer to memory that it `malloc`s from the process's heap, then copies the initial environment from the stack into this heap area. Each time the process uses the `setenv` function, `glibc` does a `realloc` to adjust the size of the area that `__environ` points to to accommodate the new value or variable. (You can download the glibc source code with `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git glibc`). To really understand the mechanism you will also have to read the Hurd code in `hurd//init/init.c:frob_kernel_process()` (git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/hurd/hurd.git hurd).

Now if the new process is only `fork`ed, without a subsequent `exec` overwriting the stack, then the argument and environment copying magic is done in `linux//kernel/fork.c:do_fork(...)`, where the `copy_process` routine calls `dup_task_struct` that allocates the new process's stack by calling `alloc_thread_info_node`, which
calls `setup_thread_stack` (`linux//include/linux/sched.h`) for the new process using `alloc_thread_info_node`.

Finally, the POSIX `__environ` convention is a *user-space* convention. It has no connection with anything in the Linux kernel. You can write a userspace program without using `glibc` and without the `__environ` global and then manage the environment variables however you like. No one will arrest you for doing this but you will have to write your own environment management functions (`setenv`/`getenv`) and your own wrappers for `sys_exec` and it is likely that no one will be able to guess where you put the changes to your environment.

Comment: Many of the files in `/proc/[pid]/` appear to have a weird encoding (someone else may know what and why). For me, simply `cat environ` would print out the environment variables in a really hard to read format.

`cat environ | strings` solved this for me.

Comment: @retrohacker This gives a more robust solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978711/how-do-i-split-a-proc-environ-file-in-separate-lines

Comment: @retrohacker UUOC.

Answer (score 38):

It is updated as and when the process acquires/deletes its environment variables. Do you have a reference which states the `environ` file is not updated for the process in its process directory under /proc filesystem?

```
xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/self/environ
```

or

```
xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/<pid>/environ
```

or

```
ps e -p <pid>
```

The above will print the environment variables of the process in the `ps` output format, text-processing (parsing/filtering) is required to see the environment variables as a list.

Solaris (not asked, but for reference I will post here):

```
/usr/ucb/ps -wwwe <pid>
```

or

```
pargs -e <pid>
```

**EDIT:** /proc/pid/environ is not updated! I stand corrected. Verification process is below.
However, the children from which the process are fork'd inherit the process environment variable and it is visible in their respective /proc/self/environ file. (Use strings)

With in the shell: here xargs is a child process and hence inherits the environment variable and also reflects in its `/proc/self/environ` file.

```
[centos@centos t]$ printenv  | grep MASK
[centos@centos t]$ export MASK=NIKHIL
[centos@centos t]$ printenv  | grep MASK
MASK=NIKHIL
[centos@centos t]$ xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/self/environ  | grep MASK
MASK=NIKHIL
[centos@centos t]$ unset MASK
[centos@centos t]$ printenv  | grep MASK
[centos@centos t]$ xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/self/environ  | grep MASK
[centos@centos t]$
```

Checking it from other session, where the terminal/session is not the child process of the shell where the environment variable is set.

Verifying from another terminal/session on the same host:

**terminal1:** : Note that printenv is fork'd and is a child process of bash and hence it reads its own environ file.

```
[centos@centos t]$ echo $$
2610
[centos@centos t]$ export SPIDEY=NIKHIL
[centos@centos t]$ printenv | grep SPIDEY
SPIDEY=NIKHIL
[centos@centos t]$
```

**terminal2:** on the same host -- do not launch it with in the same shell where the above variable was set, launch the terminal separately.

```
[centos@centos ~]$ echo $$
4436
[centos@centos ~]$ xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/self/environ | grep -i spidey
[centos@centos ~]$ strings -f /proc/2610/environ | grep -i spidey
[centos@centos ~]$ xargs --null --max-args=1 echo < /proc/2610/environ | grep -i spidey
[centos@centos ~]$
```

Comment: I do `export foo=bar` in the one bash's session (pid xxxx), then do `cat /proc/xxxx/environ | tr \\0 \\n` in other bash's session and I don't see `foo`.

Comment: I updated the above answer with an example checking the same process within shell.

Comment: You are correct. I stand corrected. Thanks. I now have to go and read my manuals to check the environment variables of a different process with in the user process group.

Comment: One more thing: I tried checking the environment attaching the `gdb`  to the pid, but still no reference there. The environment variables block in the memory gets reallocated whenever there is a change and is not reflecting in its own process' environ file in the proc filesystem, but however allows to be inherited by the child process. That means this could get easier to know intrinsic details when the fork happens, how does the child process gets environment variables copied as is.

Comment: I hope @Gilles would throw some of his torch light on this.. :-)

Comment: `/usr/ucb/ps` doesn't seem to work on Solaris 11, but `pargs -e` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Well the following is not related with author's real intentions, but if you really want to "READ" the `/proc/<pid>/environ`, you may try

```
strings /proc/<pid>/environ
```

which is better than `cat` it.

Comment: +1 for `strings`.  Keep it simple.

Comment: Agree @EdRandall, this feels like the easier approach vs `xargs --null`.

Comment: The "file" is null terminated, replace nulls with new-line and normal tools work again (with the usual caveats), e.g.: `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$$/environ | ...`

Comment: As long as the environment variable itself does not contain newlines.  Shells like BASH sometimes do that for 'exported functions'.

Comment: By default `strings` only prints strings of length >= 4. Environment variables like `A=1` will be ignored. Also, whitespace (expect space and tab) is ignored. You can change this by using `strings -n2 -w` instead.

Comment: `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$pid/environ` should be accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

I opted to temporarily attach a `gdb` session to the program and call `getenv` from there.  It probably does not work with *all* programs, and it's quite costly, but this often works:

```
echo 'p (char *) getenv("PWD")' | \
     gdb --quiet -p $(pidof emacs) | \
     sed -n 's/.*"\(.*\)"$/\1/p'
```

Comment: I was not aware of exactly how to use gdb to do that... Great process! Thanks! Fortunately (for my security concerns) this often will not work... On Ubuntu 20.04 basically default install running the same against vim, I got: `Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.`

Comment: Interesting, it seems the default for `ptrace_scope` actually changed very recently.  I did have to go `sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope'` .

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a project that does what previous answers suggested to retrieve updated variables from programs that don't update `/proc/<pid>/env`: https://github.com/LlinksRechts/getenv

This attaches to a process using `ptrace`, injects some code that calls `getenv`, prints the result, and resumes the program where it left off.

This of course follows the same limitations as the approach that uses `gdb` (namely requiring to set `ptrace_scope`), but is much faster than that (benchmarks on my PC showed ~200ms for gdb, but only 0.4ms for getenv).

Comment: I'm commenting here as your [*getenv* GitHub project](https://github.com/LlinksRechts/getenv) has issue reporting disabled: on my system (*Debian 11 bullseye*), `./getenv` does not show updated environment variables of *other* processes.

Comment: @Abdull I enabled issues - could you give a bit more details there? (which program you tried, maybe a minimal reproduction,...)

Answer (score 1):

I have created the [envps](https://github.com/henrik242/envps) utility for this:

```
$ envps 607
LaunchInstanceID=5345193B
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=no.example.ExampleExtension
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You can build it yourself using `make` or install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install henrik242/brew/envps
```