# Get the environment variables of running process in container

Tags: linux, environment-variables, docker

In a machine that runs a docker container I attach to the running container: `docker exec -it SHA1 /bin/bash`
How can I see the environment variables of the process running in the container?
I see that if I try to `cat /proc/$pid/environ` I get a permission error despite the fact that I am root. 
Why do I get the permission error? Is there another way to check the environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `cat /proc/$pid/environ` is using `ps e -p $pid`

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29132/193945

As for the permission-error, without a `Dockerfile`it can be hard to tell. Are you using SELinux ? How did you start the container ?

Have you tried exec with `--privileged` ?

Comment: I don't even know what is `SELinux`. And no I have not started with `--priviled`. How does that help?

Comment: Can you share the `Dockerfile` and how the container is built and run ?