# Auto answering password for OPENSSL using HEREDOC

Tags: linux, bash, here-document

I have the following command but it doesn't work for me...

```
cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ && openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
password
PASS
```

The output is:

```
109 semi-random bytes loaded
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
...............................++++++
...........++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for smtpd.key:
```

It should auto answer the question and put password automaticaly.

I always use `HEREDOC` for automating my Q&A on bash and work fine...

What is the problem here?

May be because of security issues, but how can we deal with such issues?

I also know about this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29111/safe-way-to-pass-password-for-1-programs-in-bash/29186#29186) but not able to resolve it.

I am trying this one: (no result)

```
#!/bin/bash
PASS="password"
printf '%s\n' "$PASS" | {
    openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 -passout fd:3
} 3<&0
```

any ideas?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169829/auto-answering-used-by-heredoc-doesnt-work-now

Comment: Yes...There where no answer @devnull. What shall I do?

Comment: What do you expect?  That the community is out here to resolve your problems instantly?

Comment: Ok...I try to be more patient...Thanks myfriend

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `-pass stdin` for `openssl` to read from `stdin`, or else, as [@XTian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118062/48083) says, it will read the password directly from the associated `tty` or `pts` device. No shell redirection will solve this.

From the same section of `man` page that [@XTian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118062/48083), gave:

> stdin     read the password from standard input.

You can do something like this:

```
cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ &&
  openssl genrsa  -passout stdin -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
PASS
```

You can also specify the password using `-passout pass:`, but this is even less secure since the password can be seen by any user using `ps` (see the man page section in [@XTian's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118062/48083)).

Comment: Excellent...This is working now

Comment: I have a question///How can I do that by doing What I tried in origin questin(no result)

Comment: pardon which one is correct? `cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ && openssl genrsa  -passout stdin -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
password
PASSW` OR `cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ && openssl genrsa  -passout stdin -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
PASSW` with one password

Comment: @Morteza, sorry, that answer was incomplete. I have intermittent internet issues just now, I think some of it actually got chopped off!. As I said you need `-passout stdin` or `openssl` will ignore the here document on `stdin` and read direct from the terminal.

Comment: @Morteza, the one with two works for me, `openssl` looks for a confirmation. As I said the answer with on `password` wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: So What should I do last? Is your answer correct with heredoc? I use two password works//1 password works...two password with different values also works :)

Comment: @Morteza, actually you only need one password when reading from `stdin`, although it won't complain if you give two.

Comment: @Morteza, there is no confirmation reading from `stdin`, so the second one is just ignored.

Comment: pardon..how about this one? `openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -out smtpd.csr` and `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in smtpd.csr -signkey smtpd.key -out smtpd.crt` and `openssl rsa -in smtpd.key -out smtpd.key.unencrypted`

Comment: @MOrteza, can't test all these now, but for some command you need `-passin` instead of `-passout`. (works for the first one).

Answer (score 4):

This is because openssl deliberately opens `/dev/tty` the controlling terminal, to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

However there are several mechanisms to specify a password, the following option is just the first from the manual page (see below), choose which one is most appropriate for you.

```
-passout pass:abcd
```

From `man openssl`

> PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS
>          Several commands accept password arguments, typically using -passin and -passout for input
>          and output passwords respectively. These allow the password to be obtained from a variety
>          of sources. Both of these options take a single argument whose format is described below.
>          If no password argument is given and a password is required then the user is prompted to
>          enter one: this will typically be read from the current terminal with echoing turned off.
>
> ```
>    pass:password
>              the actual password is password. Since the password is visible to utilities (like
>              'ps' under Unix) this form should only be used where security is not important.
>
>    env:var   obtain the password from the environment variable var. Since the environment of
>              other processes is visible on certain platforms (e.g. ps under certain Unix OSes)
>              this option should be used with caution.
>
>    file:pathname
>              the first line of pathname is the password. If the same pathname argument is
>              supplied to -passin and -passout arguments then the first line will be used for
>              the input password and the next line for the output password. pathname need not
>              refer to a regular file: it could for example refer to a device or named pipe.
>
>    fd:number read the password from the file descriptor number. This can be used to send the
>              data via a pipe for example.
>
>    stdin     read the password from standard input.
> ```

Comment: even no answer with `printf '%s\n' "$PASS" | {
    openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 -passout fd:3
} 3<&0`

Comment: I also tried this one:  `openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 -passout "pass:mypassword"`

Comment: Very strange, I just tried `openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:abcd -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024` and that works !